# "to pay their respects with messages in letters appearing on the walls" meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

Please help me to understand this sentence:

> Today fans [of Freddie Mercury] continue to visit to pay their respects with messages in
>   letters appearing on the walls.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddie_Mercury

What I understand is: Fans of Freddie Mercury continue to visit his house and even after his death, they still write their messages on his home's wall to tribute him.

Is this correct?

PS: Sorry if the thread's title is not understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

Quoting from your source:

> The outer walls of Garden Lodge in 1 Logan Place became a shrine to
>   Mercury following his death, with mourners paying tribute by covering
>   the walls in graffiti messages.Three years after his death, Time
>   Out magazine reported, "Since Freddie's death, the wall outside the
>   house has become London's biggest rock 'n' roll shrine." Today
>   fans continue to visit to pay their respects with messages in letters
>   appearing on the walls.

The last line implies: *Fans write their messages in letters which they put up on the walls of the house, as a tribute to Freddie Mercury.*